# Typescript - Record<string, any> to Object

Tags: typescript, nock

I have a `Record<string, any>` and would like to convert it to an object. I get this type unfortunately by [Nock](https://github.com/nock/nock), so I can't change it though.
But to continue working with it, I need an object. Maybe someone knows the answer, because unfortunately I have not found anything myself.

Comment: `Record<string, any>` *is* an object. I'm not sure what further transformation you want to do on it.

Comment: As the question is written, it doesn't make any sense. As other pointed out, it is already an object. So this means: You have not tried this yet (!) or you have, and have some other problem you are not telling us. So I'm going to flag this for closure until you provide more details.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're talking about so that others can help you.

Answer (score 3):

[The `Record` type is an object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

`Record<string, any>` is a type where the keys are `string` and every value is `any`. In fact you could write this type using object type notation.

```
type A = Record<string, any>
type B = { [key: string]: any }
// A and B are equivalent
```

And you can access it like an object:

```
const obj: Record<string, any> = { ... data here ... }
const aValue = obj.someProp
```

So if you have a `Record<string, any>`, you can access any `string` property like you would an object, and then you will get back an object typed as `any`. No transformation necesary.